# Can I start multiple Activities of same class for result from one Activity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

I have a class, let's name it `IntentStartingThread`, with  attributes `Activity context`, which is the `Activity` the `Intents` are started by, `Bundle data` - the data, being passed to the started `Intent` and `int resultCode`, which is the result code of the started intent.

`IntentStartingThread`'s run() basically does

```
....
Intent resultActivity = new Intent(context, ResultActivity.class);
resultActivity.putExtra("data", data);
context.startActivityForResult(resultActivity, resultCode);
```

In the class I'm gonna name `CallingActivity extends Activity` i have the constants

```
private static final int FIRST_REQUEST_CODE = 456;
private static final int SECOND_REQUEST_CODE = 457;
private static final int THIRD_REQUEST_CODE = 458;
```

and the `IntentStartingThread` objects `thread1`, `thread2` and `thread3`.

In a thread, run from the onCreate() method, in which I have a variable `Activity activity`, which is pointing to the `CallingActivity`, I call

```
thread1 = new IntentStartingThread(activity, someData, FIRST_REQUEST_CODE);
thread2 = new IntentStartingThread(activity, someData, SECOND_REQUEST_CODE);
thread3 = new IntentStartingThread(activity, someData, THIRD_REQUEST_CODE);

thread1.run();
```

`CallingActivity.onActivityResult()` looks the following:

```
if (requestCode == FIRST_REQUEST_CODE){
    thread2.run();
    //doStuff
} else if (requestCode == SECOND_REQUEST_CODE) {
    thread3.run();
    //doMoreStuff
} else if (requestCode == THIRD_REQUEST_CODE) {
    //doTheLastStuff
}
```

The running of the activity from `thread1` is okay, `thread2` is being ran and I do not seem to receive result from the second time the result activity is being ran - it does not get into onActivityResult().

Comment: So, you are using multiple threads to start an activity?

Comment: Even if the activity are started there no way for you control life cycle of Activity. i hope you can find other way to implement it

Comment: The above code and your explanation really make no sense from an Android UI perspective. Activities are for user-interaction, not to calculate some result. Look into using a Service or IntentService.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. `ResultActivity` presents a selectable list of data to the user. The three threads start three different instances of `ResultActivity`, presenting different list of data. All three instances are called from the `CallingActivity`, simply the call is in the thread.